# How to display a js object's property image in a div?

Tags: javascript, image, html

I would like to display the image property of an object written in Javascript. I have tried to use the following code, but it doesn't want to work for me. The function show_image is from here, so I know it works (it works when I try it with a 'raw' image file as well.) I also wish to be able to choose where, within a certain div, this image should show up. How would I go about doing this? The div I wish to append it too can be identified by it's classname I guess, and I think I should use "getElementById", but exactly how I would do this is a mystery.

The image does show up as an empty square, but it says "[object%20HTMLImageElement]".

Here's my current scriptcode:

```
var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'imagehere';

    card=new Object();
    card.backImage=img;
    card.height=100;
    card.width=100;

    show_image(card.backImage, 
                     276, 
                     110, 
                     'Whateverthenameis');

    function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height;
        img.alt = alt;

        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The thing that attaches the created *Image* to the DOM is [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild). In your example, you're using `document.body.appendChild(img);`, so this is the line that you'd need to change. You may also want to add another parameter to your *function*, to let you pass the *Node* you want the image appended to, too.

For example, your resulting function may have the form

```
function show_image(src, width, height, alt, parent) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;

    parent.appendChild(img);
}
```

and invoked by

```
show_image(
    'http://yummy.p.ie/photo.jpg',      // url
    100, 100, 'PIE!',                   // width, height, alt
    document.getElementById('pieShelf') // parent
);
```

With some *HTML* that looks like

```
<div id="pieShelf">Look at my yummy pie</div>
```

Comment: I still don't get the image to show though. The image name becomes "[object%20HTMLImageElement]".

Comment: You are passing a _HTMLImageElement_ as the first arg of `show_image` (parameter name `src`). It is expecting a _String_, not a _Node_. Either pass a url, or rename parameter 1 from `src` to `img` and remove the first two lines of the function's body.